# Generating PDF documents from large text files using Python's ReportLab package is slow

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, reportlab

I have a very large number of text files that I need to convert to PDFs (using Python 3.8.5), and then separate the content by page breaks. The page breaks are encoded in these text files as *form feeds* and are represented in Python with the substring `\x0c`. I am able to read the text in and split the document by these form feeds. Then, I use the package `reportlab` to create a PDF with the correct pagination. This is a condensed version of my code:

```
import glob
from reportlab.lib,enums import TA_JUSTIFY
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, PageBreak, Spacer
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.units import inch

file = glob.glob(wdir + text_folder + "/**/*.txt", recursive=True)
for i in file:
     doc = SimpleDocTemplate(i[:-4] + ".pdf", pagesize=letter, rightmMargin=72, leftMargin=72, topMargin=72, bottomMargin=18)
     f = open(i, encoding='utf-8')
     k = f.read()
     k_breaks = k.split("\x0c")
     Story = []
     styles=getSampleStyleSheet()
     styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Justify', alignment=TA_JUSTIFY))
     for j in range(len(k_breaks)):
          ptext='<font size="12">' + k_breaks[j] + '</font>'
          Story.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles["Justify"]))
          Story.append(Spacer(1,12))
          if j != len(k_breaks)-1:
               Story.append(PageBreak())
     doc.build(Story)
```

Through tracing, I've found that my code seems to reach a bottleneck on the lines

```
          Story.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles["Justify"]))
          Story.append(Spacer(1,12))
```

Although, this is really just an issue on large text files (upwards of 1 or 2 mb). Smaller text files within the 100kb range are not *too* slow, but these larger files take hours on hours. When they finish, the resulting PDFs are hundreds or thousands of pages long. I want to reduce the processing time. Is there a better way within `reportlab` to do this, or a suggested change in methodology- perhaps via a different package?

*EDIT*: I know this is many months later, but I eventually found that this issue was especially a problem for text files where form feeds were inconsistently placed (e.g., the script would process massive amounts of text where there was no clear distinction where one page started or ended).

Answer (score 2):

You can check [pdfme](https://github.com/aFelipeSP/pdfme) library. It's the most powerful library in python to create PDF documents.

I can't tell if it would be faster with those huge files, but you could give it a try and check the following code:

```
import glob
from pdfme import build_pdf

file = glob.glob(wdir + text_folder + "/**/*.txt", recursive=True)
for i in file:
     f = open(i, encoding='utf-8')
     k = f.read()
     k_breaks = k.split("\x0c")
     sections = [{"content": [k_break]} for k_break in k_breaks]
     with open(i[:-4] + ".pdf", 'wb') as f:
         build_pdf({
             "style": {"s": 12, "text_aling": "j"},
             "page_style": {"page_size": "letter", "margin": [72,72,18,72]},
             "sections": sections
         }, f)
```

Check the docs [here](https://pdfme.readthedocs.io/).